# Why my downloaded video file size is 0 byte by using fetch method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to fetch a video from a website using its URL. To accomplish this, I have written some JavaScript code. However, when I run the code, the downloaded file size is 0 bytes.

I am confident that the URL is correct because I have entered the same URL in Chrome. I was able to see the video and download it successfully.

In that website: the html is below

```
<video controls autoplay name="media">
  
  <source src="https://rexample" type="video/mp4">

</video>
```

Below is my code:

```
async function downloadVideo(link) {
      try {
      
        const response = await fetch(link,{
          mode: 'no-cors',
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
        }});

      
        const blob = await response.blob();
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = url;
        a.download = 'video.mp4';
        a.click();
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
```

Comment: From MDN: [Note that `mode: "no-cors"` only allows a limited set of headers in the request:

`Accept`
`Accept-Language`
`Content-Language`
`Content-Type` with a value of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks mostly fine, but there are a few modifications you can make to ensure it works correctly.

First, the mode: 'no-cors' option in the fetch function is preventing the response from being accessible, which could be the reason for the 0-byte file. Instead, you should remove the mode option or use mode: 'cors' to allow cross-origin requests.

Secondly, the Content-Type header you're setting in the request is not necessary. The server should already be sending the correct Content-Type header in the response, so you can remove the headers object altogether.

> ```
> async function downloadVideo(link) {
>  try {
>   const response = await fetch(link);
>   const blob = await response.blob();
>   const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
>   const a = document.createElement('a');
>   a.href = url;
>   a.download = 'video.mp4';
>   a.click();
>   URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
>  } catch (error) {
>   console.error(error);
>  }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , the reason I added no-cors is that i got below error; 
from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled. ; 

Even I removed that, I also has such error

Comment: The CORS error occurs when a web page hosted on one domain tries to make a request to a different domain. To fix it, ensure the server includes the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in its response, allowing the specific domain to make cross-origin requests. Setting the request mode to 'no-cors' bypasses the policy but limits access to response data. In summary, enable the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header on the server for the specific domain to resolve the CORS issue.

Comment: At least three of your answers (and even your comment!) appear likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.